# Amazon S3 web site parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I'm hosting a website on s3 and I have a list of users. 
Example structure: user/index.html

So when somebody want's to see a specific user he goes to url like www.example.com/user/?id=12345, what I wan't to do is use path like www.example.com/user/12345.

I hope it can be done with redirect rules, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I think I need something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RoutingRules>
   <RoutingRule><Condition><KeyPrefixEquals>user/?id=$id</KeyPrefixEquals>       </Condition><Redirect><ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>user/$id</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>  </Redirect></RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon S3 Website Configuration Routing Rules Redirect Rule Property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration-routingrules-redirectrule.html) only supports `ReplaceKeyPrefixWith`, which allows **redirection to a different path**. The rules do not support any form of logic.

Your **web application** would need to perform such logic, then redirect users to the appropriate objects in Amazon S3.

Comment: So basicly I can't do it. Unless I have some kind of web app. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon s3 does not process query string parameters and, therefore, don't return different versions of an object based on parameter values